# matplotlib.widgets.Slider with fill_between

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I'm trying to Add the slider in the plot similar to the [slider demo example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html).

I'm plotting **fill_between** which gives **PolyCollection** object.

Although I tried with *plot* too which give **Line2D** object as shown picture below, but plot doesn't update as expected as in [demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html).

[image]

code

```python
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as widgets

def get_pdf(mu, sigma=1, offset=4):
    o = sigma * offset
    x = np.linspace(mu - o, mu + o, 100)
    rv = ss.norm(mu, sigma)
    return x, rv.pdf(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
ax.fill_between(*get_pdf(0, 1), alpha=0.7)
# t = plt.fill_between(*get_pdf(2, 1), alpha=0.7) # this gives ployCollection
t = ax.plot(*get_pdf(2, 1), label='treatment', alpha=0.7)

a = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.5, 0.03])

slider = widgets.Slider(a, "shift", 0, 10, valinit=2, valstep=1)
def update(val):
    x, y = get_pdf(val)
    t[0].set_ydata(y)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

slider.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the line plot, `t[0].set_xdata(x)` needs to be set, as it is different for each call. In this particular case, `get_pdf` each time returns the same `y`.

Updating the coordinates of the `polyCollection` generated by `fill_between` doesn't seem to be possible. However, you can delete and recreate it at every update. Note that this is slower than just updating the coordinates.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as widgets

def get_pdf(mu, sigma=1, offset=4):
    o = sigma * offset
    x = np.linspace(mu - o, mu + o, 100)
    rv = ss.norm(mu, sigma)
    return x, rv.pdf(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
ax.fill_between(*get_pdf(0, 1), alpha=0.7)
t = ax.fill_between(*get_pdf(2), color='crimson', alpha=0.7)
a = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.5, 0.03])

slider = widgets.Slider(a, "shift", 0, 10, valinit=2, valstep=1)
def update(val):
    global t
    t.remove()
    t = ax.fill_between(*get_pdf(val), color='crimson', alpha=0.7)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

slider.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

Comment: after your sugession, i made few improvement and posted in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/243048/matplotlib-fixing-axis-scale-and-alignment

Comment: any idea what to do with the histogram plot? i did `del t` it doesn't clear the old plot.